# Dynamically aligning points of exsheets question on the right/left in a multicol environment

Tags: margins, multicol, exsheets

My exercise sheets contains question in two columns. Every question has points which are to be displayed as [***] either on the right or on the left. I am using `exsheets` package. It provides a default `runin` style which I set globally via `\usepackage[headings=runin]{exsheets}`

Then I define a new style as follows

```
\DeclareInstance{exsheets-heading}{runinn}{default}{
    runin = true ,
    attach  =   { main[l,vc]points[l,vc](-\marginparsep-3em,0pt) } ,
    join =
    {
        main[r,vc]title[r,vc](0pt,0pt) ;
        main[r,vc]number[l,vc](.333em,0pt)
    }
}
```

1. My plan is to dynamically detect whether a particular question gets allotted to the right column or the left (of the `multicol` environment) and then assign it a one time style of either `runin` or `runinn`. I have no idea how to do that.
2. The left column shd have points aligned left and the right column shd have points aligned right. The default provided style `runin` does the "right" job pretty well. But my crappy style `runinn` doesn't do the "left" job.
   I tried using variations like
   `points-pre-code = \flushright , points-post-code = \endflushright`
   Apart from throwing up a compilation error (which baffles me), it too does no good. Even `points-pre-code = \raggedleft` or `points-pre-code = \raggedright` changes nothing.

This is my MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{multicol,tikz}
\usepackage[headings=runin]{exsheets}

% exsheets settings
\newcommand{\rowpoints}[1]{\reversemarginpar[\foreach\x in {1,...,#1} {$\star$}]}
\SetupExSheets{counter-format=[qu]}
\SetupExSheets[question]{name=}
\SetupExSheets[points]{name=,number-format=\rowpoints}

\newcommand{\sample}{Can you answer this profoundest question of life - if two objects are greater than a third one, are they greater or smaller than each other?}

\DeclareInstance{exsheets-heading}{runinn}{default}{
    runin = true ,
    %points-pre-code = \flushright , 
    %points-post-code = \endflushright,
    %points-pre-code = \raggedright ,
    attach  =   { main[l,vc]points[l,vc](-\marginparsep-3em,0pt) } ,
    join =
    {
        main[r,vc]title[r,vc](0pt,0pt) ;
        main[r,vc]number[l,vc](.333em,0pt)
    }
}

\begin{document}

\begin{multicols}{2}
    \SetupExSheets{headings=runinn}
    \begin{question}{1}
    This one shd have a right margin
    \end{question}
    \SetupExSheets{headings=runinn}
    \begin{question}{2}
        This one shd have a right margin
    \end{question}
    \SetupExSheets{headings=runinn}
    \begin{question}{3}
        This one shd have a right margin
    \end{question}
    \SetupExSheets{headings=runinn}
    \begin{question}{4}
        This one shd have a right margin. \sample
    \end{question}
    \SetupExSheets{headings=runinn}
    \begin{question}{5}
        This one shd have a right margin
    \end{question}
        \SetupExSheets{headings=runin}
    \begin{question}{1}
        This one shd have a left margin
    \end{question}
    \SetupExSheets{headings=runin}
    \begin{question}{2}
        This one shd have a left margin
    \end{question}
    \SetupExSheets{headings=runin}
    \begin{question}{3}
        This one shd have a left margin \sample
    \end{question}
    \SetupExSheets{headings=runin}
    \begin{question}{4}
        This one shd have a left margin
    \end{question}
    \SetupExSheets{headings=runin}
    \begin{question}{5}
        This one shd have a left margin
    \end{question}
\end{multicols}

\end{document}
```

This is how it looks like

[image]

In this MWE, I have manually tried to resolve (1) which is the worst possible solution. (2) is unresolved. Any help?

**EDIT 1:**  I had posted a partial answer which I am incorporating here after deleting that answer.

The following solves the problem (2)

```
% a new question display style which fills the left margin
\DeclareInstance{exsheets-heading}{runinn}{default}{
    runin = true,
    points-post-code = \space,
    number-post-code = \space,
    attach  =   { main[l,vc]points[r,vc](0pt,0pt) },
    join =  { main[r,vc]title[r,vc](0pt,0pt);
        main[r,vc]number[l,vc](.333em,0pt) }
}
```

Incorporating the above in a new MWE :

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{multicol,tikz,tasks}
\usepackage[headings=runin]{exsheets}

% exsheets settings
\newcommand{\rowpoints}[1]{\reversemarginpar[\foreach\x in {1,...,#1} {$\star$}]}
\SetupExSheets{counter-format=[qu]}
\SetupExSheets[question]{name=}
\SetupExSheets[points]{name=,number-format=\rowpoints}

\newcommand{\sampletext}{Can you answer this profoundest question of life - if two objects are greater than a third one, are they greater or smaller than each other?}

% a new question display style which fills the left margin
\DeclareInstance{exsheets-heading}{runinn}{default}{
    runin = true,
    points-post-code = \space,
    number-post-code = \space,
    attach  =   { main[l,vc]points[r,vc](0pt,0pt) },
    join =  { main[r,vc]title[r,vc](0pt,0pt);
        main[r,vc]number[l,vc](.333em,0pt) }
}
\SetupExSheets{headings=runinn} % this new style is set as default

\settasks{
    counter-format =(tsk[a]), 
    item-indent = 0em, 
    label-offset=.4em, 
    label-align=right, 
    before-skip = 0pt, 
    after-item-skip=0pt
}

\begin{document}

\begin{multicols}{2}

    \begin{question}{1}
        This one shd have a right margin
        \begin{tasks}(2)
            \task $n$ is even 
            \task $n$ is odd 
            \task no such $n$ exists 
            \task None
        \end{tasks}
    \end{question}
    \begin{question}{2}
        This one shd have a right margin \sampletext
    \end{question}
    \begin{question}{4}
        This one shd have a right margin. 
    \end{question}

    % I am forced to manually insert this line at an appropriate place, which is found only after seeing the PDF output.
    \SetupExSheets{headings=runin} % runin is a built-in style from exsheets package

    \begin{question}{5}
        This one shd have a left margin. 
    \end{question}  
    \begin{question}{5}
        This one shd have a left margin \sampletext \\
    \end{question}
    \begin{question}{1}
        This one shd have a left margin \sampletext
    \end{question}
\end{multicols}

\end{document}
```

Gives me the following result.

[image: Problem (2) solved]

The first problem remain unresolved. I am forced to manually insert this `\SetupExSheets{headings=runin}` at an appropriate place to get the margins correct. Needless to say it is extremely tiresome. After every new question added to the sheet, I have to remove that line and insert it at a new place.

I have tried things like `\zposx` to automate it ... but even after two days I am still at bay. Any ideas?

Comment: Would you mind switching from `exsheets` to the `xsim` package? With the latter a solution would be easy...

Comment: sure why not.. i will try

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is tricky with `exsheets`. It is a lot easier with the designated successor `xsim`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[colaction]{multicol}
\usepackage{xsim,marginnote}

\xsimsetup{exercise/template=runin}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewExpandableDocumentCommand \makecopies {mm}
  { \prg_replicate:nn {#1} {#2} }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\usepackage{needspace}
\DeclareExerciseEnvironmentTemplate{runin}{%
  \par\vspace{\baselineskip}
  \Needspace*{2\baselineskip}
  \noindent
  \textbf{[\GetExerciseProperty{counter}]}%
  \GetExercisePropertyT{subtitle}{ \textit{#1}} %
  \GetExercisePropertyT{points}{%
    \docolaction
      {\reversemarginpar\marginnote{[\makecopies{\PropertyValue}{$\star$}]}}
      {[\makecopies{\PropertyValue}{$\star$}] }
      {\marginnote{[\makecopies{\PropertyValue}{$\star$}]}}%
  }%
}
{}

\newcommand{\sample}{Can you answer this profoundest question of life -- if two
  objects are greater than a third one, are they greater or smaller than each
  other?}
\newcommand{\sampleanswer}{Yes. No. Maybe. Can you repeat the question?}

\begin{document}

\begin{multicols}{2}
\begin{exercise}[points=1]
  This should have a left margin.
\end{exercise}
\begin{exercise}[points=2]
  \sample
\end{exercise}
\begin{exercise}[points=3]
  \sample
\end{exercise}
\begin{exercise}[points=4]
  \sample
\end{exercise}
\begin{exercise}[points=5]
  \sample
\end{exercise}
\begin{exercise}[points=1]
  \sample
\end{exercise}
\begin{exercise}[points=2]
  \sample
\end{exercise}
\begin{exercise}[points=3]
  \sample
\end{exercise}
\begin{exercise}[points=4]
  \sample
\end{exercise}
\begin{exercise}[points=5]
  \sample
\end{exercise}
\end{multicols}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much! I had no idea of ``xsim`` before your answer. I tried this package. It is very customizable and has a learning curve. However I faced a very strange problem with it. In the books, the question number and the [xxx] thingy is displayed after the question. This doesn't happen in articles. Though I probably need more checking. However your idea of ``\docolation`` (again something which I didn't know) gave me another idea which I have posted as an answer. please have a look.

Comment: @magguu I don't understand your comment: if I exchange `article` with `book` in my MWE the output looks *exactly the same* (if I leave header and footer aside)!

Comment: OK ... after a lot of trial and error I figured out what was happening. The odd and even pages in my book were putting right and left margins respectively. the definition of ``\reversemarginpar`` also switched accordingly. The end result was that I got the expected margins on odd pages but mirror-image of the expected margins on even pages. this appeared to me like I foolishly described in my earlier comment. once I figured, it was easy to rectify. I used ``changepage`` package and appropriate ``\ifoddpage`` directives in the ``\docolaction`` blocks to correct for this margin switching.

Answer (score 0):

Inspired by clemens' use of `\docolaction` I found a barely workable answer. This works for some cases and doesn't work perfectly for some other cases. In this MWE, I have set the number and content of questions in such a way to highlight the non-working case. The first question (and only that question) of the second column doesn't display the margin points correctly. I guess that is becasue the heading `leftmar` is applied when the current line to be printed is on the left column, but at the time of printing, the question got shifted to right column and hence the margin stay as if it is a left column. This doesn't happen if I have bigger `question` body.

I am using `\savesymbol` from `savesym` package to first save the environment `\question`/`\endquestion` and reusing later.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz,tasks,savesym}
\usepackage[colaction]{multicol}
\usepackage[headings=runin]{exsheets}

% exsheets settings
\newcommand{\rightrowpoints}[1]{[\foreach\x in {1,...,#1} {$\star$}]}
\newcommand{\leftrowpoints}[1]{\reversemarginpar[\foreach\x in {1,...,#1} {$\star$}]}
\SetupExSheets{counter-format=[qu]}
\SetupExSheets[question]{name=}
\SetupExSheets[points]{name=,number-format=\rightrowpoints}

\newcommand{\sampletext}{Can you answer this profoundest question of life - if two objects are greater than a third one, are they greater or smaller than each other?}

% a new question display style which fills the left margin
\DeclareInstance{exsheets-heading}{leftmar}{default}{
    runin = true,
    points-post-code = \space,
    number-post-code = \space,
    attach  =   { main[l,vc]points[r,vc](0pt,0pt) },
    join =  { main[r,vc]title[r,vc](0pt,0pt);main[r,vc]number[l,vc](.333em,0pt) }
}

\settasks{
    counter-format =(tsk[a]), 
    item-indent = 0em, 
    label-offset=.4em, 
    label-align=right, 
    before-skip = 0pt, 
    after-item-skip=0pt
}
\savesymbol{question}
\savesymbol{endquestion}
\newenvironment{question}[1]{
    \docolaction{\SetupExSheets{headings=leftmar}}{}{\SetupExSheets{headings=runin}}%
    \origquestion{#1}
}{
    \origendquestion\ignorespacesafterend
}

\begin{document}

\begin{multicols}{2}
    \begin{question}{1}
        This one shd have a right margin
        \begin{tasks}(2)
            \task $n$ is even 
            \task $n$ is odd 
            \task no such $n$ exists 
            \task None
        \end{tasks}
    \end{question}
    \begin{question}{2}
        This one shd have a right margin \sampletext
    \end{question}
    \begin{question}{4}
        This one shd have a right margin. %\sampletext
    \end{question}
    \begin{question}{4}
        This one shd have a right margin. 
    \end{question}
    \begin{question}{5}
        This one shd have a left margin. 
    \end{question}  
    \begin{question}{5}
        This one shd have a left margin \sampletext \\
    \end{question}
    \begin{question}{1}
        This one shd have a left margin \sampletext
    \end{question}
\end{multicols}

\end{document}
```

This is how it looks (here question no.4 shows the behavior) -

[image]

Comment: To get a working example change the line ``This one shd have a right margin. %\sampletext`` to ``This one shd have a right margin. \sampletext``